# AWS CloudFormation: Unable to attach the security groups to the instances of ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying my Laravel application to AWS using CloudFormation. I creating an ElasticBeanstalk environment and deploying my application to it. But when I tried to attach the security group to the instances, it is failing.

This is my template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  Vpc:
    Default: "vpc-dd53ada4"
    Type: String
  VpcCidr:
    Default: "172.31.0.0/16"
    Type: String
Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
Resources:
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  Application:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Pathein Directory Laravel application
  ApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - '-'
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: php-sample.zip
  ApplicationConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      Description: SSH access to Pathein Directory Laravel application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.8 running PHP 7.2
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerSecurityGroup
  Environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Pathein Directory Laravel application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      EnvironmentName: PatheinDirectoryTesting
      TemplateName:
        Ref: ApplicationConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: ApplicationVersion
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: SingleInstance
```

As you can see there is a WebServerSecurityGroup resource in my template and I am attaching it to Beanstalk resource as follow.

```
- Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
              OptionName: SecurityGroups
              Value:
                Ref: WebServerSecurityGroup
```

When I deploy it, it is failing. But if I do not attach the security group, the deployment is successful. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

This is the error in the log.

```
{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/2279aec0-e0af-11ea-9638-0239f54378b8",
            "EventId": "0f5cb020-e0b0-11ea-9e62-06135fdfc858",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "patheindirectory",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/2279aec0-e0af-11ea-9638-0239f54378b8",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-17T17:35:36.459000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to update: [ApplicationConfigurationTemplate]. "
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/2279aec0-e0af-11ea-9638-0239f54378b8",
            "EventId": "ApplicationConfigurationTemplate-UPDATE_FAILED-2020-08-17T17:35:35.723Z",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "ApplicationConfigurationTemplate",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "pathe-Appli-YX7VOE30J9B5",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-17T17:35:35.723000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "UPDATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'sg-0a306c1333b9bf33e' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'SecurityGroups'): The security group 'sg-0a306c133
3b9bf33e' does not exist (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConfigurationValidationException; Request ID: 955a0f72-5f26-4ede-a494-e748897b4c93)",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"patheindirectory-Application-1H2ZF7KLXDN5P\",\"Description\":\"SSH access to Pathein Directory Laravel application\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"PatheinDirectory\",\"Nam
espace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"},{\"Value\":\"patheindirectory-WebServerInstanceProfile-1F7RC2LIQP996\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"IamInstanc
eProfile\"},{\"Value\":\"sg-0a306c1333b9bf33e\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"SecurityGroups\"}],\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.8 running PHP 7.2\"}"
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `WebServerSecurityGroup` (SG) is not found is because you are creating the SG in a  **different VPC** then your EB environment. Specifically, you are lunching EB in a default VPC, while you seem to be creating your  SG in different VPC as specified in the following line:

```
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc # <--- your EB will be in different VPC than your SG
```

Since its not clear what you are doing with the VPC (are you launching EB in custom VPC, creating new VPC or using default VPC?), the easiest fix to your template is simply removing the `VpcId: !Ref Vpc`.

Also your **platform version is outdated** and needs to be changed. The list of available PHP platform versions is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.PHP).

I **fixed** the template and I can **verify that it works** in `us-east-1`. It launches EB and its SG in a `default VPC`. For custom VPC many more changes are required to your template, such as definitions of subnets, route tables and VPC specific changes to EB environment itself.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  # Vpc:
  #   Default: "vpc-dd53ada4"
  #   Type: String
  # VpcCidr:
  #   Default: "172.31.0.0/16"
  #   Type: String

Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
Resources:

  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation
      #VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole

  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  Application:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Pathein Directory Laravel application
  ApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - '-'
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: php-sample.zip

  ApplicationConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      Description: SSH access to Pathein Directory Laravel application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.9 running PHP 7.2 
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerSecurityGroup

  Environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Pathein Directory Laravel application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      EnvironmentName: PatheinDirectoryTesting
      TemplateName:
        Ref: ApplicationConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: ApplicationVersion
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: SingleInstance
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking through an [example template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/ElasticBeanstalk_in_VPC.template) it appears as though the configuration requires a `VpcId`, `Subnets` and `ELBSubnets` option to allow the EB setup to join a VPC rather than creating its own.

In addition you were using a previous version of `SolutionStackName`, it should be `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.9 running PHP 7.2`.

I also noticed your benefit can make use of [AWS parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types) for the VPC Id and Key name rather than hard coding which will improve the usability from the interface.

The below template fixes the above

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  Subnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  VpcCidr:
    Default: "172.31.0.0/16"
    Type: String
Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
Resources:
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  Application:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Pathein Directory Laravel application
  ApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - '-'
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: php-sample.zip
  ApplicationConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      Description: SSH access to Pathein Directory Laravel application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.9 running PHP 7.2
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile       
        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: VPCId
          Value:
            Ref: Vpc
        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: ELBSubnets
          Value:
            Ref: Subnet
        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: Subnets
          Value:
            Ref: Subnet
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value: 
            Ref: WebServerSecurityGroup
  Environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Pathein Directory Laravel application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      EnvironmentName: PatheinDirectoryTesting
      TemplateName:
        Ref: ApplicationConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: ApplicationVersion
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: SingleInstance
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It built correctly for me using this.